# TFS Build takes long time

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

In our company we use Gated Checkin to make sure commited code doesn't have any problems and also we run all of our unit tests there. We have around 450 unit tests. 
To build the entire solution it takes 15-20 seconds and for tests maybe 3 mins on my local computer. When I build it on the server it takes 10 minutes. Why is that? Is there an extra stuff that will be fired that I don't know of?

Comment: Do you run CodeAnalysis ("FxCop") both locally and on the build server?

Comment: @Christian.K Actually, I run the Code Analysis on the server but not locally. That is a good point.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that there are additional overheads (clean/get workspace is the main culprit most of the time) in the workflow prior to the actual build and then test cycle. I have seen the same behaviour myself and never really got to a point where the performance was that close to what it would be locally.

Once the build is running, you can view the progress and see where the time is being taken, this will also be in the logs.

Comment: So, there is no way to reduce the time?

Comment: You will need to look at the logs and see where the time is being spent, from there you can see what you can do

Answer (score 2):

In the build process parameters you can skip some extra steps if you just want to build the checked in code.
Set all these to False: Clean Workspace, Label sources, Clean build, Update work items with build number.

You could also avoid publishing (if you're doing it) or copying binaries to a drop folder (also, if you're doing it).

As others have suggested, take a look at the build log, it'll tell you what's consuming the time.